# How to use Reinforcement Learning for a Classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

Using Python, I'm trying to predict if an individual is eligible for a loan or not. So, my output will be either a 1 or 0.

I want to use a Reinforcement Learning approach to learn and experiment. But, I haven't found any useful resources on how to use RL in classification problems.

My question is, is to suitable to use RL or is it too complex for my problem and it's not used in similar real-world problems?

If the answer is yes, how can I apply RL in classification problems?

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594007/using-reinforcement-learning-for-classfication-problems) would be useful

Comment: I feel like it does not make any sense to use RL. RL is for sequential decision making. Is there any sequential structure (series, tree, ...) in your data?

Comment: @Harvett this won't be for production it's just for research purposes. What if for example I wanted to predict an Interest Rate where I have a couple of inputs and want to predict a percentage?

Comment: hey, do you have an answer?